# $3^x+4^x+5^x=6^x$ has exactly one real solution

Tags: calculus, roots

$3^x+4^x+5^x=6^x$ has exactly one real solution.

I took $f(x)=\frac{3^x} {6^x} + \frac{4^x}{ 6^x}+ \frac{5^x}{6^x} -1 $ it's decreasing function since $f\prime(x) < 0$. But how can I say it has exactly one real root? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Observe that equality holds when $x=3$. If you want a (slightly) less haphazard way, compute $f(0)$ and $f(5)$ and use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: But how can we get such point, like x=3?

Comment: $f(x)\to - 1$ as $x\to  \infty$ and $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to - \infty$. Now use the fact, that $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Note that $f(x) \to -1$ as $x\to\infty$ and $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you I got it now using $f(0)>0, f(5)<0$ so we can apply Intermidiate value theorem.

Comment: In this case, we just recognize the equation.  Grace Chisholm Young proved that $3,4,5,6$ is the only solution in relatively prime positive integers to the equations $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=w^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing and differentiable on $\mathbb R$ , it cannot have two distinct real roots because the theorem of Rolle would guarantee a point $c$ with $f'(c)=0$ which contradicts your result. With the comment of "Integrand", you can show that there is actually a real root, hence exactly one.

Answer (score 1):

If the derivative is always negative, this means the function is decreasing. Notice $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = -1 \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = +\infty,$$
and by continuity there must be a root. The function is decreasing implies that there can be only one root. Indeed, if $x_1 < x_2$ were both roots then
$$0 = f(x_1) > f(x_2) = 0$$
and you conclude $0> 0$.